# API Gateway GET and POST being cached - suspected CORS issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, cors, aws-api-gateway

I've created a bunch of API resources within my AWS API Gateway - these are all working perfectly fine.

I also export the definition to SwaggerUI for some user documentation and testing.

I have enabled CORS on all my calls and each calls works as expected.

The problem I just realized, is that - through swagger / Postman if I call a certain endpoint (lets say https://apiserver/api/helloWord) with a GET method, it works fine, I then immediately change the call to a POST and it fails with a 403 forbidden - if I wait 5 - 10 min, then the POST will work and the GET will fail... It's almost as if the Options method is getting cached (not sure).

I have tried adding a few headers to my Options method (including Access-Control-Max-Age, Cache-Control, Expiry etc.) with no luck.

Each API call takes in an API Key and an Authtoken - which works fine for the first call (and every other call if its the same method), until I change the method.

Doing this through the API Gateway test's work perfectly fine - although they do not use Options (noticed through Fiddler), as soon as I use Swagger UI or postman to test the calls, this issue appears.

Fiddler logs aren't really helpful, as it shows each call fetching the Options then routing to the GET or POST method - the data all looks good.

Any ideas, please?

Comment: Postman shouldn't be calling the OPTIONS method either, unless you've configured it to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using a custom authorizer? If so you should try setting the cache TTL on that to 0 and test again. If that fixes the issue, you'll have to fix the policies you're generating from the authorizer.

The policy from the authorizer is cached **accross the whole API**. So if you send a policy back that allows just the method that was called (say the GET was called and you sent a policy back that allowed the GET method), then when you call a POST method you'll get 403. You should construct a global policy in the authorizer for the client token. Then any calls throughout the API with the same token don't have to go back to the Lambda function, which saves money and latency.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I'm going to be changing our policy and see if it helps, although it does look related.